# apache-camel | camel-jetty | How to extend request header size

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

I want to send a http-get-request with camel-jetty.
There are two mandatory headers, which contain Bearer-tokens.
When the request is sent an error happens on jetty-client-side:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: JettyClient failed cause by: 500: Request header too large. Exchange[ID-BE1HL631-1658772224692-0-1]. Caused by: [org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException - 500: Request header too large]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.doTaskCompleted(JettyContentExchange9.java:162) ~[camel-jetty9-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.onConnectionFailed(JettyContentExchange9.java:128) ~[camel-jetty9-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9$1.onFailure(JettyContentExchange9.java:223) ~[camel-jetty9-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.RequestNotifier.notifyFailure(RequestNotifier.java:253) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.RequestNotifier.notifyFailure(RequestNotifier.java:239) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:567) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.lambda$executeAbort$0(HttpSender.java:361) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Request header too large
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.process(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:235) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP.sendHeaders(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:65) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:212) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.send(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:84) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:125) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:241) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP$Delegate.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:269) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:125) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:38) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:377) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:332) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:311) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.succeeded(HttpDestination.java:246) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool.proceed(AbstractConnectionPool.java:319) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$FutureConnection.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:539) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$FutureConnection.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:517) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Promise$Wrapper.succeeded(Promise.java:130) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onOpen(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:133) ~[jetty-client-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.connectionOpened(SelectorManager.java:324) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:402) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$2100(ManagedSelector.java:65) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:1069) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

If I just send one of the headers (doesn't matter which one), it works properly.
I already tried to create a separate JettyHttpComponent9 and set RequestHeaderSize and RequestBufferSize, but obviously it doesn't work.

Workaround is to use camel-http4.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, camel-jetty only supports consumer endpoints, so I'm not sure how you're sending a request, unless you're still on Camel 2.x.

In any case, there is a [requestHeaderSize](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/jetty-component.html#_component_option_requestHeaderSize) option which may help.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, thanks for the hint concerning camel 3. I'm still using camel 2.x., but requestHeaderSize didn't work. As jetty isn't supported for producer in camel3 any longer and the recomendation is to use camel-http instead (which is camel-http4 in camel 2.x) my 'workaround' seems to be the solution.

Comment: Side benefit of your workaround is you'll have less work to do if you upgrade to 3.x. And if you do upgrade, `http4` has been renamed `http` in 3.x.